# Persistent static routes on Debian 11

Tags: debian, networking, iproute

I'm trying to set up a testing lab such as the following:

[image]
P.D: Is not Metasploit, but Metasploitable.

I'm running VirtualBox, and the routers are 2 VMs running Debian 11. Each router has 2 interfaces:

```
~# ls /sys/class/net/
enp0s3    enp0s8    lo
```

For **router 1**

```
~# cat /etc/network/interfaces
[...]
# The primary network interface
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet static
        address 192.168.10.254
        netmask 255.255.255.0
auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet static
        address 192.168.100.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```

For **router 2**

```
~# cat /etc/network/interfaces
[...]
# The primary network interface
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet static
        address 192.168.100.2
        netmask 255.255.255.0
auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet static
        address 192.168.20.254
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```

I tried to add the route for **router 1** with

```
~# ip route add 192.168.20.0/24 via 192.168.100.2 dev enp0s8
```

and for **router 2** with

```
~# ip route add 192.168.10.0/24 via 192.168.100.1 dev enp0s3
```

`ip route show` for **router 1**

```
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s3 scope link metric 1000
192.168.10.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.254
192.168.20.0/24 via 192.168.100.2 dev enp0s8
192.168.100.0/24 dev enp0s8 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.1
```

`ip route show` for **router 2**

```
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s3 scope link metric 1000
192.168.10.0/24 via 192.168.100.1 dev enp0s3
192.168.20.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.20.254
192.168.100.0/24 dev enp0s8 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.2
```

Later on, I found making it this way changes are not persistent, so I tried all of this

https://www.mybluelinux.com/debian-permanent-static-routes/

And when I restart the networking service, either via `systemctl restart networking` or `/etc/init.d/networking restart` the output is

```
Jobs for networking.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status networking.service" and "journal -xe" for details.
```

`systemctl status networking.service` output:

```
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code)
Process: 478 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-enviroment (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)


router1 systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
router1 ifup[499]: RTNETLINK answers: File existis
router1 ifup[478]: ifup: failed to bring up enp0s8
router1 systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
router1 systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
router1 systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
```

`journalctl -u networking.service` output:

```
--Boot blabla hash blabla
router1 systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
router1 ifup[499]: RTNETLINK answers: No such process
router1 ifup[478]: ifup: failed to bring up enp0s8
router1 systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
router1 systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
router1 systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
--Boot blabla other hash blabla
router1 systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
router1 ifup[499]: RTNETLINK answers: File existis
router1 ifup[478]: ifup: failed to bring up enp0s8
router1 systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
router1 systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
router1 systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
```

`cat /etc/network/interfaces` for router 1:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet static
        address 192.168.10.254
        netmask 255.255.255.0
auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet static
        address 192.168.100.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
#       gateway 192.168.10.254
        up ip route del 192.168.20.0/24 via 192.168.100.2 dev enp0s8
        up ip route add 192.168.20.0/24 via 192.168.100.2 dev enp0s8
```

Then if I try to reboot the system, on startup it raise an error "Failed start raise network interfaces"

So here is where I got lost. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't post images of text!

Comment: I'm sorry. I thought it wouldn't be wrong to posting images of text. 
Is there any reason for not doing it?

Comment: The same reasons apply many other places, so it's really easy to search for. But: Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Discussed in some detail (on our meta site) at [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/80216).

Comment: Thanks, I'll be correcting this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 **up** commands.
Change it to

```
post-up ip route add...
post-down ip route del...
```

and restart network service or reboot

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I commented the post-down by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:

1. Check systemd network configuration using:

   ```
   networkctl -a status
   ```
2. Check for failed services:

   ```
   systemctl --type=service --state=failed
   ```
3. Consider using systemd over `/etc/network/interfaces`. 
   If you choose that approach, move `/etc/network/interfaces` to `/etc/network/interfaces.save` and configure your network using systemd.

To avoid all unexplained behavior,
abandon using interfaces and translate everything to systemd,
creating `xxx.network` files:

- `/etc/systemd/network/10-enp0s3.network` and
- `/etc/systemd/network/20-enp0s8.network`

Then enable systemd-networkd:

```
systemctl enable systemd-networkd
```

and reboot.